# How to calculate the integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{1-x^2}\sin(ax)\sin[a(1-x)] dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How can I calculate the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{1-x^2}\sin(ax)\sin[a(1-x)] dx$$
where $a>0$.

It seems like the integrand is well defined without any singularities, but I don't have any clue how to proceed.
Can anyone show me how to do it? Thank you

**Edit**

Following exactly what @Maxim suggested in the comment
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \operatorname {Re} \operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_0^\infty g(x) dx = \operatorname {Re} \left(\int_0^{i \infty} g(x) dx +  \pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = 1} g(x) \right).$$

taking $x=iu$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{i\infty}g(x) dx &=\frac{1}{2}ie^{i\frac{\pi}{4}-a}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}e^{-2au}}{1+u^2} du-\frac{1}{2}ie^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos (a) \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{1+u^2} du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}ie^{i\frac{\pi}{4}-a}I-i\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4} \cos (a)e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align}

The integral $I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}e^{-2au}}{1+u^2} du$ can be calculated using the method in the comment of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752678/find-int-0-infty-frac-sqrt-x-e-xb2-x2-dx).
Let $f_1(u)=\sqrt{u}$ and $g_1(u)=e^{-2au}/(1+u^2)$

\begin{align}
I &=\int_0^{\infty} f_1(u)g_1(u)du\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mathcal L[f](u) \mathcal L^{-1}[g](u) dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int_{2a}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (u-2a)}{u^{3/2}}
\end{align}
then let $u=x^2$

\begin{align}
I &=\sqrt{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2a}}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x^2-2a)}{x^2}dx\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2a)\int_{\sqrt{2a}}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (x^2)}{x^2}dx-\sqrt{\pi}\sin(2a)\int_{\sqrt{2a}}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (x^2)}{x^2}dx\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2a)I_1-\sqrt{\pi}\sin(2a)I_2
\end{align}

Making use of the parameterization technique, we have:
$$I_1=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}-2C(\sqrt{2a})+\frac{\sin^2 (\sqrt{2a})}{\sqrt{\pi a}}$$
$$I_2=-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}+2S(\sqrt{2a})+\frac{\cos^2 (\sqrt{2a})}{\sqrt{\pi a}}$$

Hence, we can obtain the desired result by substituting  $I_1, I_2$ and $I$ into original integral.

**My qustion is:**
If I am only interested in the asymptotic behavior of the original integral as $a\to +\infty$, is there any simplier way to do it without going through all these steps?

Comment: Without any poles? How about $x=1$?

Comment: @ Bernard  what I meat is that x=1 will not cause any singularity, it is saved by $sin[a(1-x)]$.

Comment: This is just a guess: use a substitution (probably $z=\sqrt{x}$) and partial fractions to write it as something that looks like [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E6)

Comment: Let
$$f(x) = \frac {\sqrt x} {1 - x^2} \sin a x \sin a (1 - x), \\
g(x) = \frac {\sqrt x} {1 - x^2} \frac {e^{i a (2 x - 1)} - \cos a} 2,$$
then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx =
\operatorname {Re} \operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_0^\infty g(x) dx =
\operatorname {Re} \left(\int_0^{i \infty} g(x) dx +
 \pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = 1} g(x) \right).$$
The non-elementary part is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {\sqrt x} {1 + x^2} e^{-2 a x} dx,$$
which has a closed form in terms of the Fresnel integrals (see the comments under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3752678)).

Comment: @ Maxim Thank you for your hint, I think it works! can you please check if my derivation is correct? I added it in my question below "Edit". If I am only interested in the asymptotic behavior of the original integral as $a\to +\infty$, is there any simplier way to do it without going through all these steps?

Comment: $e^{i \pi/4 - a}$ is $e^{i (\pi/4 - a)}$,
$$\frac {\sin^2 \sqrt {2 a}} {\sqrt {\pi a}},
\frac {\cos^2 \sqrt {2 a}} {\sqrt {\pi a}}$$ should be
$$\frac {\sin 2 a} {\sqrt {2 a}},
\frac {\cos 2 a} {\sqrt {2 a}},$$
and there are typos in what should be
$$\int_0^\infty \mathcal L[f_1](u) \mathcal L^{-1}[g_1](u) du,$$
everything else is correct. The asymptotics are obtained in exactly the same manner as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3829786), you have elementary terms plus $\int_0^\infty x^\beta/(x^2 + 1) e^{-2 a x} dx$ with $\beta = 1/2$. Apply Laplace's method to the integral.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you so much, I found all the mistakes I made in my notes with your comment. I am going to write an answer to this question to conclude it.  
One thing about the asymptotics though, since I know the exact form of $I_1$ and $I_2$, therefore by using the asymptotic form of Fresnel integral I deduce $$I_1\sim\frac{\cos (2a)}{4a\sqrt{2a}}$$
similarly, $$I_2\sim\frac{\sin (2a)}{4a\sqrt{2a}}$$
so that $$I\sim\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2a)I_1-\sqrt{\pi}\sin(2a)I_2\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cos(4a)}{4a\sqrt{2a}}$$

Comment: @Maxim However, if I apply Laplace's method to $I$ directly, I will expect to have
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac {\sqrt x} {1 + x^2} e^{-2 a x} dx\sim(-1)^n\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{\infty}x^{1/2+2n}e^{-2ax}dx\sim\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(3/2+2n)}{(2a)^{3/2+2n}}$$
By taking the first term, I lost the oscillatory factor. would you please kindly check what goes wrong in this? Thank you!

Comment: This is just a sign error, you should get $I_2 \sim -\sin(2a)/(4 a^{3/2} \sqrt 2)$.

Comment: @Maxim Ahhh~ Thank you sooo much for your help! I learned a lot from you! Have a nice one! Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @Maxim , sorry to bother you in this way, but I have recently posted a new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4884375/802023), would you mind taking a look at it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{1/2} \over 1-x^{2}}
{\sin\pars{ax}\sin\pars{a\bracks{1 - x}} \over 2}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{1/2} \over 1 - x^{2}}
{\cos\pars{2ax - a} - \cos\pars{a} \over 2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{1/2} \over 1 - x^{2}}
\bracks{\expo{\ic\pars{2ax - a}} - \expo{\ic a}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\bracks{\expo{-\ic a}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{1/2} \over 1 - x^{2}}
\pars{\expo{2\ic ax} - \expo{2\ic a}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ x^{2}}{=}\,\,\, &\
\Re\bracks{\expo{-\ic a}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{2} \over 1 - x^{4}}
\pars{\expo{2\ic ax^{2}} - \expo{2\ic a}}
\,\dd x}
\end{align}
Now,I'll *"close"* the integration along a *pizza-slice* $\ds{\mathcal{P}_{s}}$ in the first quadrant. Namely,
$\ds{\mathcal{P}_{s} =
\pars{0,R}\cup R\expo{\ic\pars{0,\pi/4}}\cup
\pars{R,0}\expo{\ic\pi/4}}$ with $\ds{R \to \infty}$. The integration along the arc $\ds{R\expo{\ic\pars{0,\pi/4}}}$ *vanishes out* as $\ds{R \to \infty}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{1/2} \over 1-x^{2}}
{\sin\pars{ax}\sin\pars{a\bracks{1 - x}} \over 2}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\Re\bracks{\expo{-\ic a}\int_{\infty}^{0}
{\ic r^{2} \over 1 + r^{4}}
\pars{\expo{-2ar^{2}} - \expo{2\ic a}}
\expo{\ic\pi/4}\dd r}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sin\pars{a - {\pi \over 4}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{2}\expo{-2ar^{2}} \over r^{4} + 1}\dd r}
_{\ds{\equiv \mathcal{I}}}
\\[2mm] + &\
\sin\pars{a + {\pi \over 4}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{2} \over r^{4} + 1}\dd r}
_{\ds{{\root{2} \over 4}\pi}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Lets evaluate $\ds{\mathcal{I}}$:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{2}\expo{-2ar^{2}} \over r^{4} + 1}\dd r =
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-2ar^{2}} \over
r^{2} + \ic}\dd r
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{2ar^{2}\ \mapsto\ r^{2}}{=}
\,\,\,
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-2ar^{2}} \over
r^{2} + \ic}\dd r =
\root{2a}\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-r^{2}} \over
r^{2} + 2a\ic}\dd r
\\[5mm] & =
\root{2a}
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-r^{2}}
\\[2mm] & \pars{%
{1 \over r - \root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}} -
{1 \over r + \root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}}}{1 \over 2\root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}}\dd r
\\[2mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\Re\braces{\expo{-3\pi\ic/4}
\bracks{\on{G}\pars{-\root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}} -
\on{G}\pars{\root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\on{G}}$ is the
[Goodwin-Staton Integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E12).

---

Finally ( see \ref{1} ),
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{1/2} \over 1-x^{2}}
{\sin\pars{ax}\sin\pars{a\bracks{1 - x}} \over 2}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\sin\pars{a - {\pi \over 4}}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\Re\braces{\expo{-3\pi\ic/4}
\bracks{\on{G}\pars{-\root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}} -
\on{G}\pars{\root{2a}\expo{3\pi\ic/4}}}}
\\[2mm] + &\
{\root{2} \over 4}\pi
\sin\pars{a + {\pi \over 4}}
\end{align}

Comment: @ Felix Marin Thank you so much for your answer. I thought at first this is basically the same approach as the one suggested by Maxim, but now I see by your choice of the complex function, there is no pole anymore. Also, very nice editing! Cheers!

Comment: ahhh~, I see the countour of integration is also different!

Comment: Hi, dear @Felix Marin, sorry to bother you, but I have recently posted a new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4884375/802023) about the integration of the hypergeometric function along a complex path, I have been struggling with it for a while. Would you mind taking a look at it? I think this is much more easier for you! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Close to $x=0$ the integrand is
$$a \sin (a)\,x^{3/2} +O\left(x^{5/2}\right)$$
Close to $x=1$
$$\frac{1}{2} a \sin (a)+\frac{1}{2} a^2 \cos (a) (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$

Now, big trouble with numerical integration.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it. what did you mean by big trouble with numerical integration?  I did not see any problem causes divergence. can you please elaborate it a little bit? thank you.

Comment: @Yolbarsop. I just tried and noticed numerical convergence issues. I am still looking at it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following exactly what @Maxim suggested in the comment
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \operatorname {Re} \operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_0^\infty g(x) dx = \operatorname {Re} \left(\int_0^{i \infty} g(x) dx +  \pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = 1} g(x) \right).$$

taking $x=iu$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{i\infty}g(x) dx &=\frac{1}{2}ie^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}-a)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}e^{-2au}}{1+u^2} du-\frac{1}{2}ie^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos (a) \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{1+u^2} du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}ie^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}-a)}I-i\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4} \cos (a)e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align}

The integral $I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}e^{-2au}}{1+u^2} du$ can be calculated using the method in the comment of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752678/find-int-0-infty-frac-sqrt-x-e-xb2-x2-dx).
Let $f_1(u)=\sqrt{u}$ and $g_1(u)=e^{-2au}/(1+u^2)$

\begin{align}
I &=\int_0^{\infty} f_1(u)g_1(u)du\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mathcal L[f_1](u) \mathcal L^{-1}[g_1](u) dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int_{2a}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (u-2a)}{u^{3/2}}
\end{align}
then let $u=x^2$

\begin{align}
I &=\sqrt{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2a}}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x^2-2a)}{x^2}dx\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2a)\int_{\sqrt{2a}}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (x^2)}{x^2}dx-\sqrt{\pi}\sin(2a)\int_{\sqrt{2a}}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (x^2)}{x^2}dx\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2a)I_1-\sqrt{\pi}\sin(2a)I_2
\end{align}

Making use of the parameterization technique, we have:
$$I_1=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}-2C(\sqrt{2a})+\frac{\sin (2a)}{\sqrt{2a}}$$
$$I_2=-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}+2S(\sqrt{2a})+\frac{\cos (2a)}{\sqrt{2a}}$$

Substituting $I_1$ and $I_2$ into the expression of $I$ yields
$$I=\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2a)\left[\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}-2C(\sqrt{2a})+\frac{\sin (2a)}{\sqrt{2a}}\right]-\sqrt{\pi}\sin(2a)\left[-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}+2S(\sqrt{2a})+\frac{\cos (2a)}{\sqrt{2a}}\right]$$
Finally, the desired integral can be written as:
$$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(\sin a -\cos a)I + \frac{\pi}{4}\sin a + \frac{\pi}{4}\cos a$$